# Economist app stuck with old issues

Tags: applications, google-apps, bugs, push-notifications, debug

This has happened to me repeatedly with the Economist app on Android. Basically the app usually automatically downloads the weekly issue by push notification, but sometimes it simply doesn't do that. When I uninstall the app and reinstall it.. it's stuck at the December 19th issue of 2015. [image]

I figured this may be a date problem, so I set the time manually on my phone.. no luck.

Any ideas? And if someone is to suggest this isn't the right stack exchange site for such questions please tell me which one I should use instead .

Comment: Contact the app maintainer?

Comment: Already did that many many many times.. they keep on sending updates that sometimes fix it and sometimes it doesn't..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically connected my android device to the internet using a VPN service ([unotelly](https://www2.unotelly.com/).. I currently live in Lebanon although when I first registered with the economist.. I was living in Canada).

Connecting via the vpn solved the problem